# Executing an insert statement and put id in a local variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlDataSource myQuiz = new SqlDataSource();

myQuiz.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yafnet"].ToString();
myQuiz.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [QuizTable]([Quiz_Title],[Quiz_Description]) VALUES (@Quiz_Title,@Quiz_Description)";

myQuiz.InsertParameters.Add("Quiz_Title",Quiz_Title.Text);
myQuiz.InsertParameters.Add("Quiz_Description",Quiz_Description.Text);

myQuiz.Insert();
Response.Redirect("QuizQuests.aspx");
```

Is there a way to get back the automatically generated ID of the new row and put it in a local variable?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Adrian

Comment: execute [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) in your C# code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913115/scope-identity-in-c-sharp-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be 100% sure that you really get the identity from your insert in your actual `QuizTable`, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (as already mentioned by Luiggi Mendoza in his comment), and not `@@IDENTITY` or `IDENT_CURRENT`.

`@@IDENTITY` might not work because [it will return the identity from the **last** insert that happened from your connection](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/). So if there is a trigger on your `QuizTable` which inserts a row in another table that has an identity column as well, `@@IDENTITY` will return the value from that second insert, and not that of the original insert into the `QuizTable` .

`IDENT_CURRENT` will return the last identity value for your table (and only for your table, so it doesn't matter if there are triggers like the one in the previous example).
But it returns the last identity value for **any** session. So if another row is inserted from another session between your `INSERT` and your `IDENT_CURRENT`, [you'll get the identity value from **that** row, not from yours.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175098.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘QuizTable’)
```

It returns the last IDENTITY value produced in a table, regardless of the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.
IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

Comment: But if another session does an insert into the `QuizTable` after your insert, but before your `IDENT_CURRENT` call, you'll get the identity value of the other insert, not yours (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365118/6884) for detailed information)

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian De Barro: hi you can use following code to get inserted record id and save in variable

in your sqlquery add following statement:

```
return @@IDENTITY
```

and your C# code will be as follows:

```
    SqlConnection cn = new   
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);        
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procname, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter str = new SqlParameter("name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    str.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    foreach (SqlParameter par in param)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
    }
    string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    cmd.Dispose();
    cn.Close();
    return name;
```